# Intellij IDEA checkstyle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I've got a problem trying to import my check-style to IDEA 14.
That's what I do:

1. File -> Settings -> Inspections -> Import
2. There I choose my `checkstyle.xml` and then I don't know why but TempProfile is created.
3. Hmm, ok, looks like this TempProfile can check my code using my `checkstyle.xml` but it doesn't!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Go to the Checkstyle configuration page via File → Settings, then typing `checkstyle` into the search box:

[image: IntelliJ config editor]

Press the *plus* icon to add your checkstyle.xml. Activate your checkstyle.xml by clicking the checkbox in the column labeled *Active*.

That's it!
If you want real-time scans, you can go to the Inspections dialog and activate the real-time scan:

[image: IntelliJ Inspections Dialog]

Comment: Oh no! Unfortunately I don't have "checkstyle" in "Other Setting". There's Vim Emulation only =(

Comment: @MaximGotovchits which plugin? I am also interested in solving this issue

Comment: Had installed Version 4.5.2 that I used and configured in Idea 14 one year ago. Now there is no "checkstyle" in "Other Setting" although the plugin is installed. Already did a reinstall and "Invalidate Caches / Restart" but checkstyle doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ThomasJensen Could you please elaborate how to enable the real-time scan. And thanks for the steps to import checkstyle.xml
Would something that works in eclipse work the same way in IntelliJ?

Comment: @NickDiv Added screenshot for inspections.

Comment: Is there a way to make "code reformatting" follow this "checkstyle" too?

Answer (score 42):

In the new version you need to install a plugin called `CheckStyle-IDEA`

[image]

[image]

Comment: After installing checkstyle as plugin you first need to click "Apply" or "OK" before you can find it. (took me now 10 min to find it, I even restarted IntelliJ, but only after I clicked "Apply" it really got installed.

Comment: @GrgKro good thing I saw your comment, I was dealing with the same issue

Comment: can somebody also let us know how to configure the suppressions.xml if its defined as variable in checkstyle.xml

Comment: I think if checkstyle version matches with xml file version, you did not need config anything.