# Checkstyle: how to disable Missing package-info.java file?

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

Can I disable somehow Checkstyle warning?

> Missing package-info.java file.

My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: How are you configuring checkstyle?

Comment: I always change the xml configuration file manually.

Comment: Can you share you configuration file then?

Comment: Which section of the config file you want to see? The full xml is so big.

Comment: The modules you have configured, of course.

Comment: I have not configured it yet. Actually this is the purpose of my question. I have not find anything in the documentation about how to disable checking the package-info.java file. Documentation: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't configured anything yet, and you are using IntelliJ, this means you are using the *Sun checks* configuration. You may not like this answer, but don't shoot the messenger ...

- Download a copy of [sun_checks.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/checkstyle-7.1.1/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml). Make sure that you modify the Checkstyle version in the URL to the one you are using (*important!*). To find out the version, select the Checkstyle-IDEA plugin in IntelliJ's *Plugins* dialog; it gives the version number in the description text.
- Remove the `<module name="JavadocPackage">...</module>` from the XML.
- [Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26957047/1005481) the resulting file as a new Checkstyle configuration and use that.

There is currently (as of Checkstyle 7.1.1) no other way to disable a rule from the standard configuration.

If you just want to suppress a single violation, or a group of violations, you may also consider the many [suppression configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023351/1005481). In order to suppress one rule entirely, you would still have to change the XML, so the above method is better.