# Enable custom CheckStyle in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm trying to enable a customer CheckStyle in IntelliJ.
I have already followed the steps to add my custom .xml file to the CheckStyle plugin ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955766/intellij-idea-checkstyle)) but it is not showing up as an option in the CheckStyle Rules dropdown box.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k7nP.png)

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Did you press *Apply*?