# Android Studio CheckStyle configuration is missing from the setting tree

Tags: android-studio, settings

I need to set custom config for the plugin CheckStyle-IDEA on my Android Studio. It should be done by going to **Settings >** either (depending on Android Studio version) **Tools** or **Other Settings > CheckStyle** as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955766/intellij-idea-checkstyle). But as you can see below, despite my installing of the plugin (and restarting, also tried "Invalidate Cache/ Restart") it does not appear.

[image]

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.2. Any ideas ?